Shadcn/Radix NavigationMenu positioning issue
I'm using Shadcn as my UI library and I'd like to center their Navigation Menu (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/navigation-menu). Currently, its align to the left of the trigger (see attached demo from official docs - Getting started trigger). How can I center content around the trigger and in the same time take care of the free space (i.e. if there is not enough space to center the content, center it as much as possible). Any ideas?

i'm little bit confuse about what do you want to try because there is no illustration, but what i understand you trying to center or positioning dropdown navigation menu right?
here the dropdown of naviation menu is overflowing screen and want i to center it until at least Push menu

on tailwindcss, i select dropdown menu element through navigation menu and then positioning it


tell me if this does not work on you or i have misunderstanding

Hey @Rio Rifaldi were you able to solve this ?

@HaryanviDeveloper i'm just play around documentation of tailwindcss. when facing this issue i remember that tailwind has an orbitary value, so i used it

This code automatically adjust position to left/right based on available space
//states 
const [position, setPosition] = useState<string>('[&_div.absolute]:right-auto [&_div.absolute]:left-0');

// logic
useEffect(() => {
    if (menuRef.current) {
        const menuRect = menuRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const spaceOnLeft = menuRect.left;
        const spaceOnRight = window.innerWidth - menuRect.right;

        // Set position based on available space
        if (spaceOnLeft > spaceOnRight) {
            setPosition('[&_div.absolute]:left-auto [&_div.absolute]:right-0');
        } else {
            setPosition('[&_div.absolute]:right-auto [&_div.absolute]:left-0');
        }
    }
}, [menu]);
 

// ui
<NavigationMenu className={position}>...</NavigationMenu />


